# HTML email download links

Tags: html-email

I've created an HTML email with a few links to download a PDF, however every time you click the link it opens your browser and the download dialog pops out. Is there anyway to just have it download directly to your computer without having to open your browser?

Comment: An email program generally isn't capable of browsing the web, so unless you make the pdf an attachment, you will need to use the browser to get to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, web links are always opened in a web browser. The alternative would be to attach the PDF to the email.